# Where do I place the frequency adverb "often"?

Tags: word-order, adverb-position

Imagine the following situation:

Person `A` says to person `B`, that `B` will be the target of taunt/sneers/ridicule etc.
Is it possible to formulate the following sentence (regarding the word order)?

> "You will often be made fun of."

or

> "You often will be made fun of."

---

*I know that it sounds like a dumb question, but as a German student I have still much to learn about the English language.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You will often be made fun of."

The above sounds better for sure.

Adverbs of frequency usually go before the verb, not before the auxililary.